# How to replace facade code in ngrx effects Angular?

Tags: angular, ngrx, facade

I am using facade pattern with ngrx. I am calling facade methods inside the ngrx effects but I have read that it is not a good practice. I would like to know how can I resolve it.

My code is given below:

**My Effects code :
**

```
closeCountSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(CountActions.CountActionTypes.CLOSE_COUNT_SUCCESS),
      switchMap((action: fromActions.CountSuccess) => {
        this.facade.resetCountList();
        this.facade.setPageNumber({ pageNumber: 0 });
        this.facade.fetchCountList({ page: 0, size: 20 });
        this.facade.setCount();
        this.openSimpleSnackbar(
          this.translateService.instant('content.count-is-successfully-closed'),
          5000,
          G3SnackType.Success
        );
        return of(new fromActions.WizardCloseDialog());
      })
    )
  );
```

My Facade code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as detailsActions from '../../count-details/store/count-details.actions';
import * as actions from '../../count-list/store/count-list.actions';
import { CountDef, CurrentBalanceResponseDef } from '../../shared/interfaces/current-balance-def.interface';
import * as fromActions from './count.actions';
import * as fromSelectors from './count.selectors';
import { CountState } from './count.state';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CountFacade {
  constructor(private store$: Store<CountState>) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    this.store$.dispatch(new fromActions.WizardOpenDialog());
  }

  closeDialog(): void {
    this.store$.dispatch(new fromActions.WizardCloseDialog());
  }

  getDialogOpened$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store$.select(fromSelectors.isOpened);
  }



  fetchCountList({ page, size }) {
    this.store$.dispatch(new actions.GetCountListRequest({ page: page, size: size }));
  }

  resetCountList() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new actions.Reset());
  }

  setPageNumber({ pageNumber }): void {
    this.store$.dispatch(new actions.SetPageNumber({ pageNumber: pageNumber }));
  }

  setCurrentCount(): void {
    this.store$.dispatch(new detailsActions.SetCurrentCountRequest());
  }
}
```

If you know how it can be done in better way then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as follow:

```
import * as CountListActions from '../../count-list/store/count-list.actions';
import * as CountDetailsActions from '../../count-details/store/count-details.actions';

closeCountSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(CountActions.CountActionTypes.CLOSE_COUNT_SUCCESS),
      switchMap((_: fromActions.CloseCountSuccess) => {
        this.openSimpleSnackbar(
          this.translateService.instant('content.count-is-successfully-closed'),
          5000,
          G3SnackType.Success
        );
        return of(
          new CountActions.WizardCloseDialog(),
          new CountListActions.SetPageNumber({ pageNumber: 0 }),
          new CountListActions.GetCashClosingListRequest({ page: '0', size: '20' }),
          new CountDetailsActions.SetCurrentCountRequest()
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

Comment: Even though i think there is no usecase for an effect here, I would split that in several effects. (subscribe to one action => dispatch one action). With that pattern, you have a maintainable flow. For sure, you can subscribe in multiple effect to the same action.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you strongly to take a look at the documentation. On the linked page you will find a diagram that describes very well the responsibilities of the individual elements in the NGRX framework.
[Diagram](https://ngrx.io/guide/store#diagram)

As you can see, there is no connection between effects and the UI Layer (snackbar, translation, ...). Don't use effects like an event manager.

With the following (pseudo)-code, I want to give you an idea, how to deal with the pages state inside components and where to use UI elements:

**count.reducer.ts**

```
const CountState = {
  listCount: number;
  pageNumber: number;
}

on(resetCount, (state) => ({
  ...state,
  listCount: 0,
  pageNumber: 0,
}))
```

**count.actions.ts**

```
const resetCount = createAction('[Count] reset');
```

**count.selectors.ts**

```
const selectState = createFeatureSelector(COUNT_STATE_FEATURE_KEY);

export const selectListCount = createSelector(
  selectState,
  ({ listCount }) => listCount,
);

export const selectPageNumber = createSelector(
  selectState,
  ({ pageNumber }) => pageNumber,
);
```

**count.facade.ts**

```
export class CountFacade {
  listCount$ = this.store.select(selectListCount);
  pageNumber$ = this.store.select(selectPageNumber);

  constructor(private readonly store: Store);

  resetCount() {
    this.store.dispatch(resetCount());
  }
}
```

**count.component.ts**

```
export class CountComponent {
  listCount$ = this.facade.listCount$.pipe(
    map(listCount) => if (listCount === 0) { 
      this.snackbar.open(
        this.translate.instant('...'),
        5000,
        G3SnackType.Success
      ));
    }
  );

  constructor(
    facade: CountFacade,
    snackbar: SnackbarService,
    translate: TranslationService, 
  ) {}
}
```

**count.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf={ 
  listCount: facade.listCount$ | async,
  pageNumber: facade.pageNumber$ | async
} as vm>
  <p>{{ vm.pageNumber }}</p>
  <button (click)="facade.resetCount()">Reset</button>
</ng-container>
```